# SAS DM 'close table'

Tags: sas, dm, display-manager

to open a table in SAS we can use the DM "VT {tablename}" command.

What is the equivalent command to CLOSE the viewtable window???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... this command will close the viewtable window (replace {libref.dataset} with your data), but submitting it repeatedly will continue closing other viewtable windows that might also be open so you might want to tweek it a bit if that's an issue.

```
dm 'next VIEWTABLE:libref.dataset; end;';
```

Comment: Just what I needed - thanks.  Ville - the code below will close all windows if submitted repeatedly:

Comment: You could also enclose it in a macro like this (credit to http://sasrunner.blogspot.com/ for this tip )

%macro closevts / cmd;
%local i;
%do i=1 %to 20;
next "viewtable:";end;
%end;
%mend;

Comment: Assign `next viewtable;winclose` to a function key (I use F12)... hitting it repeatedly will close all open viewtables, one after the other.